# How can I calculate distante between rects in D3?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm working on this project and I need to calculate the distance between rects? Some idea?

My goal is to replicate one hart about Covid from this piece from The Washington Post: https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2020/health/coronavirus-herd-immunity-simulation-vaccine/

Below the picture is the code who I used to generate this chart.

Thanks!!

[image]

```
export function main(){
  createSVG()
  build()

}

let offset = {top: 20, left: 70}
let screenWidth = 800 - offset.left
let screenHeight = 400 - offset.top


function createSVG() {
    let container = d3.select('#container')
    svg = container.append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'canvas')
    .attr('width', screenWidth + offset.left)
    .attr('height', screenHeight + offset.top)
}

function build() {
    let rectWidth = 15
    let rectHeight = 15
    let randomMovementLimit = 9

    let people = []
    for(let i = 0; i< 100; i++){
      const cellX = i % 10
      const randomX = Math.random() * randomMovementLimit - 3
      const x = offset.left + cellX * (rectWidth + 10) + randomX
      const cellY = Math.floor(i / 10)
      const randomY = Math.random() * randomMovementLimit - 3
      const y = offset.top + cellY * (rectHeight + 10) + randomY
      const infected = Math.random() > 0.5
      people.push({x: x, y: y, cellX: cellX, cellY: cellY, infected: infected})
    }

    console.log(people[0])

    const infectedPeople = people.filter
    const healtyPeople = people.filter

    let rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(people)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d,i) {
            return d.x
          })
        .attr('y', function(d,i) {
          return d.y
          })  
        .attr('height', rectHeight) 
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .style('fill', (d, i) => {
          return d.infected ? "red" : "blue"
        }) 

        .attr('rx', 5)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate distance from center of each rectangle using pythagorean theorem.  I think but haven't tested if I remember right that the center of each rectangle is at d.x + rectWidth/2 and d.y - rectHeight/2.  Initialize rectWidth and rectHeight outside of the build function so they are within scope.

Example to get newly infected rectangles at distance less than social_dist from the previously infected:

```
let social_dist = 6;

rects.filter(function(d,i){ 
 for (let p of infectedPeople){
   let xDist = (p.x + rectWidth/2) - (d.x + rectWidth/2);
   let yDist = (p.y - rectHeight/2) - (d.y - rectHeight/2);
   let dist = Math.sqrt( xDist*xDist + yDist*yDist );  
   if (dist < social_dist){
   return true;
 }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: You can replace Math.sqrt ( x * x + y * y ) with Math.hypot ( x, y )